# Sql Query Select From an update, records, that were not updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm using Sql server 2012

Just curious if there is a way to do such a thing...

My update query looks like

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.TowerNumber=b.SiteNumber
FROM tower a 
INNER JOIN sites  b 
ON a.sitenumber = b.sitenumber
```

what i would like to do after the ON line is something like

```
EDIT **select records that did not match the ON statement**
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Please add a tag for it to help get the attention of people who can help you.

Comment: Sorry i thought i did, let me try again : I am trying to Find the Records my Update statement did not update, is that more clear ?

Comment: SQL Server, sorry about that

Comment: The ones that already had ``TowerNumber`` set to ``SiteNumber``?

Comment: ...before the update was run?

Comment: Why not just join your current query on the update table?

Comment: @Aiias
I'm up for how ever it is done just asking how to do so , couldnt figure it out own my own

Comment: @mzedeler well im setting sitenumber to tower number actually, but no I would like an after or if possible during the transaction select statement that shows me records that did not update because the where ON criteria was not matched

Comment: What data is in the update table? Sites that need to be updated? Sites that have not yet been updated? Towers that need to be updated? Towers that have not yet been updated?

Comment: @Aiias update table i thought was something sql server created to make the transaction i was simply throwing an example out there , update table does not belong to My created tables, i'm only working with Sites and Tower tables

Comment: I don't think there is a way to query the server during a transaction to get a list of rows that has been touched by an update.

Comment: @mzedeler That would be the `OUTPUT` clause

Comment: Yes. It seems to be just right. I have learned something new today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns all rows that wouldn't be touched by the update because the `ON` (join) criteria wasn't met.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tower
 WHERE sitenumber NOT IN
     (SELECT sitenumber
       FROM sites)
```

Comment: Would the result be still guaranteed in a "highly concurrent" environment? I'm thinking the result could change between the moment of the select and the update operation below.

Comment: Yes. This would surely not be usable in an environment with concurrent updates.

Comment: ...unless you run the query inside a transaction where the update was done as well.

Comment: An obvious solution is to write a stored procedure. What most people tend to do when SQL seems to be inadequate.

Comment: @mzedeler - A transaction wouldn't necesarily guarantee this. You would need to have a lock on the entire table.

Comment: All I can see is that it requires ``SNAPSHOT`` isolation level which seems to avoid some of the most eager locking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger and then make use of the `DELETED` table. It should contain the rows that were updated during the update operation so what you are looking after are the rest of the rows in the initial table (select rows from your table where  not in `DELETED` table)

Comment: A trigger would be overkill. Could just `OUTPUT` the primary key values of the updated rows.

Comment: Indeed, OUTPUT is the actual tool for this job.